# (FIXED) Armature not reflecting the weight paint to its left/right counterpart. Not symmetrizing. + random thumb confusion

Tags: modeling, armature

In a previous model, the first one done, the weight paint was fine and no issues were occurring, however in this newer one, there is. When weight painting on "Left shoulder" bone, the same weight painting principles will not apply to the one on the right ("Right shoulder"). Pressing the "x" symmetry will only apply the weight paint for the Left shoulder to both shoulders, when in the previous work, it did not do that. The names are all correct (afaik). Symmetry and Subdivision modifiers have been applied previously. Armature modifier is used. When making the armature, symmetry was used to create the right side. The Left bones were made on the model's left and not the viewer's left. I transferred the armature from the previous model to the new one and the same issue occurs. Tried searching for a fix, couldnt find one. Does anyone know why this is? Also, side note, on the thumb, the edges are all sharp (and not being 'marked sharp').Increasing topology didnt necessarily fix it. Did I forget an important step?|| Thank you for the help !|| File --> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable 'Mirror Vertex Groups' also? With this enabled it seems to work fine on my end.
[image: Mirror]

Also personally I recommend using suffixes like "_L" and "_R" like you've done with the fingers, quicker to read and type, less chance for typos. That said your current does work.

As for these sharp bits on your fingers, after look at the normals you can see that some polygons are flipped by the ones that don't have cyan lines on them:
[image: Normals]

You can fix this by selecting everything by pressing A, then alt+N to open up the Normals Menu and select 'Recalculate Outside', or press shift+N. What this will do is automatically make the normals face outwards with most models that don't have any odd topology.
[image]
[image]

Hope that helped.

Comment: It's easier to see inverted faces by checking Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlay menu.

Comment: @JohnEason Ah yes, you're right. My way is a bit roundabout.

Comment: @Zoukeau Thank you so much! I didnt realize the mirror thing had a drop down to select mirror vertex groups . And recalculating normals also fixed the issue for the thumb. Thank you-

Comment: @JohnEason thank you ! this was also helpful--